# How to create a new cache driver with Laravel 3?

Tags: php, caching, laravel, laravel-3

I've created a new file in application/libraries/fnmemcache.php, with:

```
namespace Laravel\Cache\Drivers;
class FNMemcache extends Sectionable {
   // ...
}
```

When I set the "fnmemcache" driver in the cache.php config file it doesn't detect my new cache driver. I've also tried with the method `Cache::extend()` in start.php but it's the same thing.

Having a look at the cache.php file (factory method) in laravel directory it seems it would never work as it have a switch with the predefined cache drivers and if we don't specify one of them an exception is thrown.
This would be easy modifying the core, but of course I don't wanna do that.

Comment: Dunno much about Laravel, but the `factory` method is only called if the `driver` method doesn't find a driver. Assuming the `driver` method is being called first, and you've `extend`ed, it should work.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, if your driver is located in `application/libraries` you shouldn't be namespacing it under `Laravel\Cache\Drivers`. So you should have `class FNMemcache extends Laravel\Cache\Drivers\Sectionable` instead.

You mentioned the `Cache::extend()` method, this is what you need to hook into. Check out [this line](https://github.com/laravel/laravel/blob/master/laravel/cache.php#L55), see how it first checks for any existing registrars? This is how you register your own drivers.

The [`Cache::extend()`](https://github.com/laravel/laravel/blob/master/laravel/cache.php#L97) method actually adds your driver. Your closure should return an instance of your driver.

```
Cache::extend('fnmemcache', function()
{
    return new FNMemcache;
});
```

You can then set the config, or use the driver at run time.

```
Cache::driver('fnmemcache')->set('key', 'value');
```